# Facebook Access Token for Single User Application

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, server-side

I'm creating an application on Facebook that will only ever have one user: me. I'm not making a GUI for the application, which means that there's no client side auth.

Is there a way that I can use my username and password or some other app information to get an access token for myself?

I'm familiar with the refresh token flows and everything for OAuth applications for other people, but I've never done this without some sort of Facebook login button, especially on a one person application. I'm happy to hard code in my user information.

I've tried using this:

```
access_token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=' + config['app_id'] + '&client_secret=' + config['app_secret']
token_response = urllib.urlopen(access_token_url).read()
access_token = token_response.replace('access_token=', '')
session = FacebookSession(
    config['app_id'],
    config['app_secret'],
    access_token,
)
```

But that doesn't give me an access token specific to my own account, only one for the application itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out. Here's what I did:

I went to the Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and then got an access token from there for my application.

Once I had the token I used this URL to get a long lived token using that access token:

```
token_exchange_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
                      client_id=APP_ID&
                      client_secret=APP_SECRET&
                      grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
                      fb_exchange_token=ACCESS_TOKEN'

exchange_response = urllib.urlopen(token_exchange_url).read()
access_token = exchange_response.replace('access_token=', '')
access_token = access_token[:access_token.index('&')]
```

I then saved that access_token and on any subsequent call I can update the access_token using that code whenever in order to make sure it's refreshed.